# Basic CSS goes wrong? So confused

Tags: css, html

Recently, my CSS codes are not working properly; I just wanted to create a div, but it doesn't show any background color or anything. Other CSS stuff works, like font-families etc...

I am so confused if I am doing something wrong or it is a browser mistake or something:

```
<div id="div">
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

And my css:

```
    body{
background-color:black;
}

#div{
width:200px;
height:100px:
background-color:white;
}
```

Example you can see here: http://milka.zemskekure.cz/index.html

What am I doing wrong, seriously, I am so mad about it. Thanks.

Comment: You need a semicolon after your height declaration, not a colon.

Comment: use [W3C CSS validation service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) next time not to waste energy for confusion

Answer (score 14):

`height` needs to end in a semicolon, not colon.

Syntax errors will usually make it so every rule declared before it works fine, but everything after it is ignored.

Comment: Oh god I am dumb and tired. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a colon `:` after your `height:100px` instead of a semicolon `;`, so your height and background rules are being ignored.